Unknown gas fees of TON TVM smartcontract
I've tested TON smartcontract.
I don't understand the gas price calculation.
This is the test NFTEmpty smartcontract:
() recv_internal(int msg_value) impure { }
No more. No includes, no methods. Just this single line.
This is how I deploy it:
    async sendDeploy(provider: ContractProvider, via: Sender, value: bigint) {
        await provider.internal(via, {
            value,
            sendMode: SendMode.PAY_GAS_SEPARATELY,
            body: null,
        });
    }

// ....

    let nftEmptyConfig: NFTEmptyConfig = { };

// ....

    beforeEach(async () => {
        blockchain = await Blockchain.create();

        nftEmpty = blockchain.openContract(NFTEmpty.createFromConfig(nftEmptyConfig, nftEmptyCode));

        deployer = await blockchain.treasury('deployer');

        const deployResult = await nftEmpty.sendDeploy(deployer.getSender(), toNano('0.01'));

});

    it.only('validate cost', async () => {
        let nftEmptyBalance = (await blockchain.getContract(nftEmpty.address)).balance;
        console.log((toNano('0.01') - nftEmptyBalance) / 400n);
    });

console.log prints:
for sendMode: SendMode.PAY_GAS_SEPARATELY: 209n
for sendMode: SendMode.NONE: 1605n
What is it? Why?
This is not a storage fee. This is not a forward fee.
I can find no explanation!
https://docs.ton.org/v3/documentation/smart-contracts/transaction-fees/fees-low-level#computation-fees
